# Game of life in Python, why my temp_board is not what I expected?

Tags: python, algorithm, conways-game-of-life

I'm trying to solve conway game of life but I think I'm stuck. I'm counting the surrounding cells which I think I'm getting it correctly. However, when I assign those numbers to a temp_board and when I print temp_board, the values are all wrong.

I put it into the temp_board to evolve to the next generation. I know this is not the best code but I'm trying to iterate so I'm trying to solve it in the simplest way first.

```
class Solution(object):
    def gameOfLife(self, board):
        """
        :type board: List[List[int]]
        :rtype: void Do not return anything, modify board in-place instead.
        """
        m = len(board)
        n = len(board[0]) if m else 0

        temp_board = [[0] * n] * m

        def count_cell(i, j):
          list_of_tuples = [(i-1, j-1), (i-1, j), (i-1, j+1),
              (i, j-1), (i, j), (i, j+1),
              (i+1, j-1), (i+1, j), (i+1, j+1)]

          count = 0
          for l in list_of_tuples:
            x, y = l
            if x >= 0 and y >= 0 and x < m and y < n:
              if x is not i or y is not j:
                if board[x][y] == 1:
                  count += 1

          return count

        for i in range(m):
          for j in range(n):
            cell = board[i][j]
            count = count_cell(i, j)
            temp_board[i][j] = count
            #print('(%s, %s) has %s' % (i, j, count))
        print(temp_board)

"""
            if cell == 1:
              if count < 2:
                temp_board[i][j] = 0
              elif count is 3 or count is 2:
                temp_board[i][j] = 1
              elif count > 3:
                temp_board[i][j] = 0
            else:
              if count == 3:
                temp_board[i][j] = 1
        """

board = [[0,0,0,0,0],
    [0,0,1,0,0],
    [0,0,1,0,0],
    [0,0,1,0,0],
    [0,0,0,0,0]]

Solution().gameOfLife(board)
```

This is the result

```
➜  game-of-life git:(master) ✗ python main.py
0
1
1
1
0
0
2
1
2
0
0
3
2
3
0
0
2
1
2
0
0
1
1
1
0
[[0, 1, 1, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1, 1, 0], [0, 1, 1, 1, 0]]
```

The weird thing is when I print each cell count, it's all correct. But when I print the temp_board, it's all wrong. I'm sure I miss something obvious.

Comment: You say the values are wrong. What values were you expecting?

Comment: I'm expecting the one that prints vertically.

Comment: problem is `temp_board = [[0] * n] * m`

Comment: @furas can you elaborate please?

Comment: it creates `m` references to the same list `[0]*n`. You need `temp_board = [[0]*n for _ in range(m)]`. Try `temp_board = [[0] * n] * m` on http://pythontutor.com and you see visualization with references as arrows.

Comment: I can give you a simple answer to your [recently deleted question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40330352/how-do-i-achieve-the-same-result-without-using-python-groupby) if you're interested.